# 'Justify-content:flex-end' puts flex content outside of the parent box in IE 11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an issue where when I apply `justify-content: flex-end` to a child element(Blue border) puts the box outside of the parent element(Red border) on IE 11 alone.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3u5wnuh0/3/).  [Open it on IE11 and chrome]

**Am I doing something wrong here?**

PS: The parent's are positioned absolute as there's a need for the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Since you use absolute positioning all over, there is no point in using Flexbox, since it will have no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please add also this css in your css code because you have added position absolute to this div

**CSS**

```
.testimonial__dots{left: auto; right: 0;}
```

Comment: Think this actually fixed it. I was trying to do `left:0`, which messed up the flex. But `left:auto` is brilliant. 
Will accept the answer after cross checking!

Comment: yes its work but as per css standard add left: auto; when you add right: 0;

Comment: That's not necessary I guess, though I was writing the same answer but wrote it first.

Comment: There is no _per CSS standard_ that says to do like that. The default  value of `left` is `auto`, so no need to add that, unless its been set earlier to something else.